# How to use for loop in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am having a list of variable like below

allModules = ['module1', 'module2', 'module3', 'module4', 'module11']

I want to use loop then print all the module one by one.

Please let me know the **syntax** and how to perform this in **Jenkins Declarative pipeline**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pure declarative pipelines don't support loops. Use a [script step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script). There's actually an example on that page that does exactly what you want.

A more readable and concise (IMO) solution would use iterators, like so:

```
steps {
   script {
      allModules.each() {
         echo it
      }
   }
}
```